# Split a column into mutiple columns based on different symbols

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 V1  V2  V3
 a   b  X:12..500(1)
 c   d  Y:34..1000(-1)
```

And I want to split the last column into different columns

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
a   b   X   12  500  1
c   d   Y   34  1000 -1
```

I have tried to use "str_split" in package "stringr", but it seems could not recognize ".."

```
 test <-data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$V3,":",2))
```

I believe there is many other ways to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(transform(df1, V3 = gsub("[:.()]+", ",", V3)), V3, 
                 into = paste0("V", 3:6), sep=",")
#  V1 V2 V3 V4   V5 V6
#1  a  b  X 12  500  1
#2  c  d  Y 34 1000 -1
```

---

Or without using any packages

```
cbind(df1[-3], read.table(text= sub(",$", "",
    gsub("[:.()]+", ",", df1$V3)), sep=",", col.names = paste0("V", 3:6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

@akrun provided a good solution

I will just add the reason why `str_split` or `strsplit` does not recognize "..", this is because period . is a metacharacter in R with a special meaning: period . matches any single character.

To use with strsplit, you can use either:

```
a="X:12..500(1)"
strsplit(a, split="\\..")
strsplit(a, split="..", fixed=TRUE)
strsplit(a, split="[.].")
```

See [Regular Expressions as used in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)